# SQL Server adding ? before and after cell value when converting from XML

Tags: xml, excel, sql-server-2014

I have a C# application that takes an Excel (`.xlsx`) file, converts it to XML, passes it to SQL Server for conversion and validation.

This has worked well for years, but I now have a file where a couple of the cells get `?` added to the start and end of the value. The XML doesn't reflect them, but there must be a special character hidden from view.

Here is a copy of the XML and T-SQL to see the results:

```
DECLARE @x xml = '<Root>
 <Row>
  <ITEMNO>1</ITEMNO>
  <PARTSOURCE>BUY</PARTSOURCE>
  <QTY>1</QTY>
  <CUSTPARTNO>‭10-0306‬</CUSTPARTNO>
  <CREV>XYS</CREV>
  <DESCRIPT>CAP,CER,10PF,50V,NP0,RF,0402</DESCRIPT>
  <REFDESG>‭C96‬</REFDESG>
  <WORKCENTER />
  <ASSYNUM>18-0074-01 REV J</ASSYNUM>
  <ASSYREV />
  <ASSYDESC />
  <CUSTNO>2519</CUSTNO>
 </Row>
</Root>'

SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY
  x.importBom.query('ITEMNO/text()').value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)')+
  x.importBom.query('DESCRIPT/text()').value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'))rowNum,
  x.importBom.query('ITEMNO/text()').value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)') itemno,
  UPPER(x.importBom.query('PARTSOURCE/text()').value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')) partSource,
  x.importBom.query('QTY/text()').value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') qty,
  x.importBom.query('CUSTPARTNO/text()').value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') custPartNo,
  x.importBom.query('CREV/text()').value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')crev,
  x.importBom.query('DESCRIPT/text()').value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')descript,
  UPPER(x.importBom.query('WORKCENTER/text()').value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'))workCenter,
  x.importBom.query('REFDESG/text()').value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')refDesg,
  x.importBom.query('CUSTNO/text()').value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')custno,
  x.importBom.query('ASSYNUM/text()').value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')assynum,
  x.importBom.query('ASSYREV/text()').value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')assyrev,
  x.importBom.query('ASSYDESC/text()').value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')assydesc
FROM @x.nodes('/Root/Row') AS X(importBom)
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR(@x = NULL))
```

The `CUSTPARTNO` and `REFDESG` fields both get the `?` in the SQL Server table, but no other columns have it. This is an example from the server of the CUSTPARTNO value: `?10-0306?`

When creating the XML, I do the following to remove some special characters and unneeded spaces at the end:

```
cellValue = cellValue.Replace("\r", "") //carriage return
                     .Replace("\n", " ")//new line
                     .Replace("\t", "")//tab
                     .Trim();
```

This does not affect the results.

How can I "see" the hidden special characters?

And, what is the best way to remove them from the cell so they are not added in the SQL Server tables?

Comment: @pnuts, I am aware that the user can trim the values (and it works), but I cannot rely on the user to always do that prior to upload. This is especially true since the user will not see it in Excel to know they need to run the TRIM (or any) function prior to upload.

Comment: I take it back, TRIM didn't work. I had to write a fancy excel formula =MID(B2,2,LEN(B2)-2). This removed the unknown characters prior to upload. I still want to prevent it from my code, but this works for now.

Comment: Your initial text contains invisible Unicode characters which *can't* be converted to ASCII (VARCHAR). Had you used NVARCHAR(MAX), there would be no issue. Whether you want these Unicode values is another matter

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos As i told you below, using NVARCHAR does not change the effect. Check it out, I posted some code... But I'm not experienced with unicode characters. Do you think it might change something to set `LANGUAGE` option?

Comment: @Shnugo actually it does, but the original text needs to be Unicode as well. As it is, it's ASCII, ie the xml literal doesn't start with `N`. Adding this fixes the conversion problem at least.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I've just voted on one of your other answers, where you missed the vote points just because you were some seconds late... You've earned it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this is still an open issue, but I was curious...

If you slowly step through with the cursor you see that in the given places the cursor doesn't move forward... This is what the HEX-editor shows

[image]

In both cases your values are framed by unicode characters 2D20 and 2C20.
2D20 is the "georgian small letter hae" and 2C20 is "glagolitic capital letter yeri". Maybe this helps you to understand where this is coming from.

According to Panagiotis Kanavos it works if you change the XML's declaration to

```
DECLARE @x xml = N'<Root> ...
```

and then use `NVARCHAR` in your `.value()` calls

btw: Your query using `.query()` and then `.value()` can be shortened doing so.

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY
  x.importBom.value('ITEMNO[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    + x.importBom.value('DESCRIPT[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'))rowNum,
  x.importBom.value('ITEMNO[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') itemno,
  UPPER(x.importBom.value('PARTSOURCE[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')) partSource,
  x.importBom.value('QTY[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') qty,
  x.importBom.value('CUSTPARTNO[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') custPartNo,
  x.importBom.value('CREV[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')crev,
  x.importBom.value('DESCRIPT[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')descript,
  UPPER(x.importBom.value('WORKCENTER[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'))workCenter,
  x.importBom.value('REFDESG[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')refDesg,
  x.importBom.value('CUSTNO[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')custno,
  x.importBom.value('ASSYNUM[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')assynum,
  x.importBom.value('ASSYREV[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')assyrev,
  x.importBom.value('ASSYDESC[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')assydesc
FROM @x.nodes('/Root/Row') AS X(importBom)
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR(@x = NULL))
```

Comment: Actually, the OP *does* cast to VARCHAR(MAX), which is probably what causes the problem. Casting to NVARCHAR(MAX) instead would have preserved the characters. Whether these characters are desired or not though, is another matter. They can't be TRIMmed because they aren't whitespace

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, right, I've tried this, but with NVARCHAR the same effect occurs...

Comment: That's because the string literal is ASCII, it doesn't start with an N. The data is mangled right from the declaration. Changing it to `DECLARE @x xml = N'<Root>` removes the `?`characters

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Thank you for beating me to the obvious!

Comment: Thank you to you both!!!. At least it doesn't display the ? anymore. Is there a way to remove those and any other "hidden" characters?

Comment: @davids If you've to deal with these two characters always, you should be able to find out, how and why they are added. Anyway: You might read it into a NVARCHAR variable, REPLACE these two unicode characters with empty strings and convert the result to VARCHAR.

Comment: We receive files from many sources. I am not sure how many have non-ascii characters, nor which characters they may be. Fortunately, it doesn't happen often, but now I don't have to worry about it. Thanks again.

Comment: It's not 2D20/2C20. It's 202D and 202C. Namely the left-to-right override followed by pop directional formatting. These are coming from someone using right-to-left culture.